# Losing Resources due to tax: what happens to the tax dice afterward?

Tags: burning-wheel

I have Resource B3, with 2 dice of tax from previous failed rolls.

I fail another test. Let's say it's Routine. Now the tax has reduced my Resources to 0. According to the book, I permanent lose a die of Resources, bringing me to B2. I can't find anything in the book specifying what happens to the tax dice, though.

- Do my tax dice go away, or am I now at B2 (taxed to B0)?
- If I fail another Resources test while already taxed to B0 (using cash to make the test at all, presumably), will my Resources immediately fall to B1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must Get a Job to recover taxed dice. BWG doesn't mention any other way to recover Resources. You're now B2 with 2 taxed dice, with an effective Resources of B0.

> Unlike the body, Resources don't recover on their own. They must be actively replenished (BWG 372).

That the number of taxed dice decreases when your Resources are depleted is both common sense and analogous to:

> If you're taxed and you advance, increase your maximum exponent and taxed exponent by one (BWG 373).

If you fail a Resources test with B2 and 2 taxed dice (getting help, etc., because you can't roll zero dice), your Resources will deplete to B1. Better hope that job pays off before you have to make another Resources test!  Low exponent Resources is brutal, so find help, use loans, and get cash from treasure and rewards.